# Partition usage

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am using dual boot of Windows 11 and Ubuntu.
I see a lot of partitions in Ubuntu. I want to find out the partitions that contain Windows or Ubuntu operating system files. Then I want to merge  theremaining partitions.
I checked the partitions by running `df -h` and opening the Disks app in Ubuntu. The results are as below:

Results of `df-h` :

[image: df-h result]

Disks application:

[image: Disks]

Which partitions are used by operating systems?

Comment: Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012 & release of Windows 8. You have very old BIOS boot on MBR(msdos) partitions. Your system is UEFI. Conversion to gpt will totally erase drive, so good backups required of data, if you decide to correct install. Your df -H does not match your Disks output. You also show another drive?